# How to say "To lose" as in to "lose a team member"

Tags: vocabulary

I"m trying to figure out how to say to "lose" as in to lose a member of a team or (in my case) a member of a club. For example, how would you translate, 
"this year my school's student council lost a couple of great representatives"

Would you use the term "输了几个很好的代表？”

Comment: **输** is the opposite of win - not the lose you're looking for. **失去** or **丢失** would be more fitting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"输了几个很好的代表？” means a council gambled with their great  representatives,then they lost.

"this year my school's student council lost a couple of great representatives"

今年，我们校学生会失去了几位出色的学生代表。

Most of the time,We can use 失去 for lost。but 失去 indicates some bad conditions. “What happend? politic conflicts or death”。

add an explanation.

今年，由于涉及到毕业，我们校学生会失去了几位出色的学生代表。

今年，由于毕业的关系，我们校学生会失去了几位出色的学生代表。

---

Edited:
After more consideration,
I think it is better to use either of the two。

失去 means something lost which you wish did not.If you were sorry for the reelection ,you could use 失去。

Comment: So, if we lost them because of reelection (but I still think it is a bad thing) you would say “失去”？

Comment: Also, what does "涉及 ” mean in this context?

Comment: @Stephen `涉及` means `involving`, `relating to`, etc. in general. I would prefer the second example than the one with `涉及`.

Comment: @Jacob We would use `失去` instead of `输` useless there is a competition (a win/lose situation) for 2 groups to fight for their representatives.